# apache camel sql component ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: java, oracle, apache-camel, camel-sql, ora-00947

This is my Java DSL route:

```
        from("seda:singlePersonChannel")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Person bean: ${body}")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Person person = exchange.getIn().getBody(Person.class);
            exchange.getOut().setBody(person.toSqlMap());
        }
    })
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Inserting into PERSON values: ${body}")
    .to("sql:INSERT INTO person (given_name, family_name) VALUES " +
    ":#givenName, :#familyName");
```

The console shows properly formatted DML:

```
Sql = INSERT INTO person (given_name, family_name) VALUES :1 , :2 , OriginalSql = INSERT INTO person (given_name, family_name) VALUES ?, ?, Error Msg = ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Both bind variables have values, so it's not a problem with nulls:

```
15:20:58.622 INFO  [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - seda://singlePersonChannel][route2] Person bean: Person{givenName=Given Name -593520961, familyName=Family Name 1883898232}
15:20:58.622 INFO  [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - seda://singlePersonChannel][route2] Inserting into PERSON values: {givenName=Given Name -593520961, familyName=Family Name 1883898232}
```

And yet Oracle is returning:

```
ORA-00947: not enough values
```

For the sake of completness my config is:

```
    <!-- the JDBC data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@DB-SVR-1:1521:DEV112A" />
    <property name="username" value="integration" />
    <property name="password" value="integration" />
</bean>

<bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

The original statement had 15 columns & values and was giving the same error. BTW, all the table columns are nullable.

Comment: you are missing parenthesis in you insert statement:
INSERT INTO person (given_name, family_name) VALUES (:1 , :2)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of syntax of `VALUES`, values should be inclosed by brackets `()`

```
VALUES ?, ?
```

So, it should be

```
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Inserting into PERSON values: ${body}")
.to("sql:INSERT INTO person (given_name, family_name) VALUES(" +
":#givenName, :#familyName)");
```

Comment: Well spotted! I couldn't see the wood for the trees, evidently.